# Minimum number of terms of strictly increasing minimal sequence whose product is square.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, oeis

[Ron Graham's sequence](http://oeis.org/A006255) is a neat bijection from the positive integers to the non-primes, defined as following:

> $a(n)$ = smallest $m$ for which there is a sequence $n = b_1 < b_2 < \dotsc < b_t = m$ such that $b_1 \cdot b_2 \cdot \dotsc \cdot b_t$ is a perfect square.

Here are some examples:

```
n | a(n) | example sequence | minimum t | product
--+------+------------------+-----------+---------
1 | 1    | [1]              | 1         | 1^2
2 | 6    | [2, 3, 6]        | 3         | 6^2
3 | 8    | [3, 6, 8]        | 3         | 12^2
4 | 4    | [4]              | 1         | 2^2
5 | 10   | [5, 8, 10]       | 3         | 20^2
6 | 12   | [6, 8, 12]       | 3         | 24^2
7 | 14   | [7, 8, 14]       | 3         | 28^2
8 | 15   | [8, 10, 12, 15]  | 4         | 120^2
```

I'm interesting in finding proof for any of the following (equivalent) conjectures that have been made about this sequence:

1. $n \cdot a(n)$ is nonsquare for all nonsquare $n$.
2. The minimum value of $t$ is never equal to $2$. (See [A066440](https://oeis.org/A066400).)
3. Let $b(n)$ be the least integer $k > n$ such that $kn$ is square. Then $b(n) - a(n) > 0$. (See [A255167](https://oeis.org/A255167).)

---

### Scatterplot of $b(n) - a(n)$.

Notice that there is not an obvious lower bound.
[image: A255167]

---

### Scatterplot of the minimum values of $t$.

Notice that $A066440(n) \neq 2$ for the first 10,000 terms.
[image: A066440]

Comment: is $t$ also minimized? because maybe for the same value of $m$ you can find different values of $t$. (for example if there is a square between $n$ and $m$.)

Comment: Great question: first minimize $m$ then minimize $t$.

Comment: oh ok, thanks.${}$